# what should i put in this if statment to save the the current array value to a variable

Tags: php

```
if (preg_match('/^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$/', $buffer, $matches));
{
    $variable = ?;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, and specifically, one you have not put any effort into solving.

Comment: You want to save what your regex matched to $variable?

Comment: yes. Ive been trying for hours. I dont know how.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831002/what-is-a-regular-expression-that-matches-all-us-phone-numbers-no-extension for context.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: hehehe, programmers quiz: for helping someone you have to find all pieces of the question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

In your case the $matches array holds what you are looking for. It is always a good idea to check the documentation first. Especially for something documented well.